# Is this extension of the real numbers a field? It involves a unit of infinity.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, real-numbers

Is this extension a field? Or perhaps some other structure?

The extension depends on two basic ideas:

1. A definition for a unit of infinity, the same as one given by Roger Penrose, and
2. The infinity unit, like the imaginary $i$, forming a new number when paired with a real number. These pairs may be referred to as **array numbers**. They do not, therefore, follow rules similar to transfinite or hyperreal arithmetic.

**Definition**: A **unit of infinity** is represented by the infinity symbol "$\infty$" and indicates a **single line array** of the real numbers. $\infty^{n}$ indicates an $n$-dimensional array. $\infty$ is not a number and is unsigned. The exponent $n$ is either an integer or $\infty$.

> Comment: Penrose uses this as a notation (not a number system) for $n$-real-dimensional space where $\infty^{n}$ "expresses that this continuum of points is organized in an $n$-dimensional array" (Road to Reality, 2004, chapter 16.7, p. 379). Here, unlike with Penrose, $n$ can be a non-positive integer.

**Arithmetic rules**: Since the $\infty$ unit always has a real part, arithmetic rules for the array numbers are the same as for polynomials, and not, as mentioned above, transfinites or hyperreals. So for example,

1. $x$ + $x{\infty^{1}}$ $\cdots$ + $x{\infty^{n}}$ is irreducible
2. $x{\infty^{n}}$ + $y{\infty^{n}}$ = $(x$ + $y){\infty^{n}}$
3. $x{\infty^{n}}$ $\cdot$ $y{\infty^{p}}$ = $(x$ $\cdot$ $y){\infty^{n+p}}$
4. and so on

Note that the reals are a subset of the array numbers when $n = 0$.

Comment: I am not sure what extension of $\mathbb{R}$ you mean. Already "real $n$-dimensional space" is not a field, for $n>1$.

Comment: The extension is made by including the array numbers as defined.

Comment: I'm not sure Penrose's book could be taken as defining new things in mathematics, though perhaps it is. Nevertheless, without properly and slightly more extensively defining things, I'm afraid this is going to remain unaddressed.

Comment: @Joanpemo I would be happy to try to define things more extensively and properly. What do you see as deficient?

Comment: Can you give an example of an arithmetic difference between these numbers and $\mathbb{R}[z,z^{-1}]$, where we identify $z$ with $\infty$? The interpretation of the symbol $\infty$ should have no impact on the formal arithmetic beyond motivating it.

Comment: @Taylor I'd like to agree, but I am not sure if $z$ is intended to be restricted to being a complex number or not. Anyhow, $\infty \cdot \infty^{-1} = 1$ and $\infty$ + $\infty^{-1}$ is in lowest terms. Hope this helps.

Comment: From a quick look at Penrose's RTR §16.7, he seems to neither subtract nor divide these "infinities". So he doesn't need them to form a field. He just wants an invariant notion of "dimension" (= # of degrees of freedom) for functional-analytic spaces perhaps, one that is finer than set-theoretic cardinality (I'm not quite sure if I am interpreting him correctly).

Comment: @darijgrinberg Correct. Penrose says the infinities are only a notation and he does not use them in any arithmetic. And yes, he wants a more useful notion of dimension than afforded by set-theoretic cardinality. I also want an invariant notion of dimension, hence the similarities of my work to Penrose and Wheeler, a happy coincidence of symbol and definition.